# Vue 3 composition API with ref

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, inertiajs, laravel-echo

I have Vue3 with composition api and Inertia with Laravel backend. I am using laravel echo to comunicate with soketi websockets server.

This is an SPA (Single page application using Inertia routing)

My question is related with ref on templates.
On first page load, calendar ref is always defined no problems.

But if I go to other views and return to this component again, calendar ref is null inside listen callback.

It is related with some vue lifecycle that I cannot understand.
It is possible to set ref calendar manually?

I already tried getCurrentInstance() from vue, set ref from function, etc.

[link to vue 3 ref docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#ref-on-component)

```
const calendar = ref(null)

onMounted(() => {

      window.Echo.channel('myChannel')
      .listen('PlanningChanges', (e) => {

        console.log(calendar.value) //is null after second load

      })

})

<template>
   <Child ref="calendar"
   </Child>
</template>
```

Comment: Do you have any wrappers for Child  with v-if?

Comment: No.. I see a lot of people with similar problems with v-if on child components, not my case.

Comment: I tried the same, but instead of Echo. I set setTimeout and it works perfectly. Could you try console.log(calendar.value) directly in onMounted?

Comment: I also have an refresh function, to update calendar component. Its exactly the same code, and not problems on that. It seems to be something related with Inertia lifecycle or from laravel echo.

Comment: @Andrii if I place console.log(calendar.value) on onMounted its always defined. But when event listen occurs, its null (only on second page load).

Comment: When I implement the same functionality. in onMounted I have added window.Echo.private("campaigns." + usePage().props.uuid).stopListening('.event');..... Also I have added onBeforeUnmount to destroy listener too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add

```js
onBeforeUnmount(() => {
    window.Echo.channel('myChannel')
      .stopListening('PlanningChanges')
})
```

it can be case that listened stays. But instance is already other one.

Comment: Thanks @Andrii, you save my day. It works now. It was the case, instance was another one.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your lifecycle hook from `onMounted()` to `onUpdated()`.

```
onUpdated(() => {
  window.Echo.channel('myChannel').listen('PlanningChanges', (e) => {
    console.log(calendar.value);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but not... that is not the problem.. is something related with Inertia lifecycle or laravel echo.